# Почему форма с сайта не отправляется в базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, html-form

У меня на сайте есть форма, скрипт отправления формы в бд, но почему то он не работает, помогите пж.
html

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST" class="form">
                    <div class="input-wrap">
                        <p class="phone-on-form" >Номер<br> телефона</p>
                        <input class="input" type="phone" placeholder="+380 Номер телфона" name="tel">
                        
                    </div>
                
                <p class="call-to-action">Шаг №1: Выберите удобный вам мессенджер</p>
                
                <div class="buttons">
                        <button type="submit" data-submit class="btn-ms facebook">
                            <img src="img/lgt-icon-facebook.svg" class="icon"></img>
                            <p>Messenger</p>
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" data-submit class="btn-tg telegramm">
                            <img src="img/lgt-icon-telegram.svg" class="icon"></img>
                            <p>Telegramm</p>
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" data-submit class="btn-vb viber">
                        <img src="img/lgt-icon-viber.svg" class="icon"></img>
                        <p>Viber</p>
                    </button>
                </div>
                </form>
```

js

```
$(function () {
  $('.btn-ms').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var url = $(this).data('target');
    location.href = 'messenger.com';
});

  $('.btn-tg').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var url = $(this).data('target');
    location.href = 'tmet';
});
  $('.btn-vb').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var url = $(this).data('target');
    location.href = 'viber';
});
});
```

php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['num'])){

    // Переменные с формы
    $name = $_POST['num'];
    
    // Параметры для подключения
    $db_host = "localhost"; 
    $db_user = "login"; // Логин БД
    $db_password = "pass"; // Пароль БД
    $db_base = 'name'; // Имя БД
    $db_table = "tablename"; // Имя Таблицы БД
    
    // Подключение к базе данных
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);

    // Если есть ошибка соединения, выводим её и убиваем подключение
  if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
      die('Ошибка : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
  }
    
    $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (num) VALUES ('$num')");
    
    if ($result == true){
        echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
    }else{
        echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
    }
}
?>
```

за ранее спасибо

Comment: Ты можешь хотя бы написать, **как именно** не работает ? Не отправляется? Отправляется но пишет ошибку? Какую? Что вообще происходит когда ты пытаешься отправить, можешь словами написать?

Comment: Меня перенаправляет по ссылке, и в бд ничего нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы не вызываете свой PHP-скрипт.
Да, он у вас прописан в атрибуте `action` формы, но ни одна из кнопок на самом деле не отправляет форму. Каждая из ваших кнопок выполняет перенаправление, которое вы задаёте в JS-функции, а собственно отправки формы не происходит, ибо

```
    event.preventDefault();
```

То есть буквально: «Предупредить выполнение события по умолчанию».

У вас есть выбор: заменить кнопки, например, на радиокнопки, а по отправке формы сначала писать в БД, а потом обычным PHP'шным `header("location: ...")` перенаправить туда, куда вам нужно (так бы делал я); или же оставить всё как есть, но в JS-функции ещё AJAX'ом дёрнуть ваш PHP-скрипт (считаю это решение переусложнённым).
Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте в комментариях, обновлю ответ.

### UPDATE: Примерное решение на радиокнопках

Код примерный, сразу говорю (бэкенд особо не проверял — накидал примерно, ибо я бы делал на PDO). Там есть мои комментарии, они в квадратных скобках и с пометкой *A. P.*. Да, и ещё я несколько улучшил код, если что-то непонятно, снова пишите в комментарии.

#### HTML

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST" class="form">
                    <div class="input-wrap">
                        <label for="num" class="phone-on-form" >Номер<br> телефона</label>
                        <!-- [Тип для телефонов — tel, а не phone — A. P.] -->
                        <!-- [У вас в PHP переменная называется num, поэтому здесь name тоже должен быть num. Ну или наоборот, но поскольку тип tel, пусть будет num — A. P.] -->
                        <!-- [Ещё можно добавить шаблон валидации телефона, погуглите атрибут pattern — A. P.] -->
                                                <input class="input" type="tel" placeholder="+380 Номер телефона" id="num" name="num">
                        
                    </div>
                
                <!-- [Немножко наведём красоту по доступности для слепых — A. P.] -->
                <p id="messenger-type" class="call-to-action">Шаг №1: Выберите удобный вам мессенджер</p>
                
                <div class="buttons" role="group" aria-labelledby="messenger-type">
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="Facebook">
                            <img src="img/lgt-icon-facebook.svg" class="icon"></img>
                            <p>Messenger</p>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="Telegram">
                            <img src="img/lgt-icon-telegram.svg" class="icon"></img>
                            <p>Telegram</p>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="Viber">
                        <img src="img/lgt-icon-viber.svg" class="icon"></img>
                        <p>Viber</p>
                    </label>
                </div>
                    <p><button type="submit" id="go" name="go">Отправить</button></p>
                </form>
```

#### PHP

```
<?php
// [Я не очень понимаю, зачем эта проверка — A. P.]
if (isset($_POST['num'])){
    // [Переменные переопределять не будем, у вас там путаница — A. P.]
    // Параметры для подключения
    $db_host = "localhost"; 
    $db_user = "login"; // Логин БД
    $db_password = "pass"; // Пароль БД
    $db_base = 'name'; // Имя БД
    $db_table = "tablename"; // Имя Таблицы БД
    
    // Подключение к базе данных
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);
    // [Честно, я бы советовал вам применять PDO: во-первых, это красиво ©, а во-вторых, можно было бы поймать исключение, а не делать вот эти вещи — A. P.]
    // Если есть ошибка соединения, выводим её и убиваем подключение
  if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
      die('Ошибка : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
  }
    // [Давайте подготовим запрос, чтобы к вам никто не пролез с SQL-инъекцией — A. P.]
    $result = $mysqli->prepare(sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (num) VALUES (?)"), $db_table);
    $result->bind_param("s", $_POST['num']);
    $result->execute();

    // [Поскольку мы хотим сделать редирект, уберём echo. По-хорошему, такие ошибки надо логировать в файл — A. P.]
    // [А вот теперь возьмём значения радиокнопок из формы и определим, куда перенаправлять — A. P.]
    $redirect = [
        'Facebook' => 'https://messenger.com',
        'Telegram' => 'https://t.me',
        'Viber' => 'https://some.url.to.viber'  // [Понятия не имею, какой у него URL — A. P.]
    ];

    header(sprintf('location: %s', $redirect[$_POST['messenger']]));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но я только учусь, можете пожалуйста сказать как в php сделать что бы location работал по разному на разные кнопки

Comment: Дело в том что нельзя сделать радио кнопками

Comment: хочу за ранее попросить, если ты не будешь переделывать или поснять мне как сделать,я пойму, ты и так единственный кто из 3 сайтов нормально ответил, за что огромное спасибо, но пожалуйста скажи нет, что бы я твой вопрос отметил ответом

Comment: А почему нельзя радиокнопки? Собственно, смотри, что я предлагал: берёшь радиокнопки, вешаешь им один `name` на всех, но даёшь разные `value`. Потом тупо этот `value` загоняешь в `header("Location: ...")`. Так, может быть, непонятно на пальцах, но если с радиокнопками решение подойдёт, набросаю в ответе примерный код.

Comment: Да, спасибо, напишите пожалуйста как сделать через чекпоинты, и еще, возможно у меня какая-то ошибка в php, я попробовал без js запустить и мне пришел в бд только id без номера

Comment: ой, радиокнопки

Comment: Обновил ответ с примерным решением на радиокнопках. Будут вопросы — задавайте, рад помочь, тем более, что мы с вами из одной страны)

Comment: @VovaMaistruc **из 3 сайтов нормально ответил** - это естественно, вы слишком большой кусок кода приводите с кучей проблем. Советую вам код писать и  тестировать по маленьким кускам. Написали запрос без переменных - проверили. Добавили переменную `$num` с вручную записанным значением - проверили. Добавили форму - проверили. Ну посмотрите на свой код, у вас в переменной $num откуда что-то возьмется? Простой CTRL+F уже дает понять, что нигде, кроме как в запросе, **num** не встречается. Такие ошибки можно и нужно находить самому.